# I'd like some help installing and running Minecraft on Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, java, minecraft

So, just today I installed Lubuntu 13.10 on my piece-of-crap laptop and I absolutely LOVE how fast it is.  I installed Java 7 successfully, and I downloaded the Minecraft.jar (Minecraft fo Linux/Other) files at https://www.minecraft.net/download.  The first thing I did was drag the Minecraft.jar to my desktop.  I then right-clicked it, went to properties, made sure it was marked as executable, and then selected "open with..." but I didn't find Java 7 Runtime Environment nor anything Java-related.  I then tried running it via terminal (I forgot the command but I believe it went along the lines of "java -jar minecraft.jar").  I also tried using "sudo chmod a+x minecraft.jar" to ensure that it was indeed executable.  Yet none of this worked.
   Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!  ^-^

--------------------Devon

-EDIT- Should I just switch to a distribution that I know can run Minecraft?

Comment: Okay, so I found what the problem could [possibly] be, and that is that although the file NAME is Minecraft.jar, the file TYPE is still considered a .zip.  Anyone know how to convert the file?

Answer (score 0):

In my memory, most people I know use `OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime` to run Minecraft because it doesn't work with `OpenJDK 7`, but it works well with `OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime` for me.
Try to right click → `Properties` → `Open with` → `OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime` → `Set as default`.

Comment: I installed Java 7 Runtime Environment.  When I had Ubuntu 13.10 on this same laptop, it worked fine.  I just installed Lubuntu 13.10 on my laptop because it's a very low-end laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
java -version
```

into the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)

to see if java is infact installed. If it is not type

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

And you should be set

Comment: I already said that I do indeed have java installed.  It's just that whenever I right-click the Minecraft.jar file and go to "open with..." it does not include anything that has to do with java.